# Actualizar datos de una tabla a otra

Tags: sql, sql-server

Saludos tengo el siguiente query:

```
SELECT *
INTO regiones2
FROM Regiones
```

Lo utilizo para insertar datos de una tabla a una existente, pero me gustaría saber si hay una forma que en vez de insertar este actualice es decir si en la tabla de regiones se creo un nuevo registro, por query este actualice todos los registros que le hacen falta a la tabla de regiones2 sin duplicar la que ya antes estaban insertadas.

Comment: Sería de utilidad que indicaras la estructura de las 2 tablas. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza la sentencia [`merge`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) que te permite, con una sola instrucción:

- Insertar los registros nuevos
- Actualizar los que hayan cambiado
- Eliminar los que se hayan borrado

Suponiendo que ambas tablas tienen exactamente la misma estructura, y que es:

```
id
NombreRegion
Campo1
Campo2
```

Donde la llave primaria es el campo `id`, la sentencia quedaría así:

```
 merge Regiones2 as dst
 using Regiones as src
    on dst.Id = src.Id
  when matched then 
update
   set   NombreRegion = src.NombreRegion
       , Campo1 = src.Campo1
       , Campo2 = src.Campo2
  when not matched by target then
insert (Id, NombreRegion, Campo1, Campo2)
values (src.Id, src.NombreRegion, src.Campo1, src.Campo2)
  when not matched by source then
delete
;
```

La lógica parte de la comparación de la clausula `on`, en este caso:  `on dst.Id = src.Id`

- Cuando hay un par de registros que cumplen la condición (uno en cada tabla), se ejecuta la cláusula `when matched` que, en este caso, es un `update` que actualiza lo que haya podido cambiar en la tabla origen hacia la tabla destino. Acá se podría refinar y agregar más condiciones con un `and` para evitar lanzar `updates` superfluos.
- Cuando hay un registro en la tabla de origen, pero no hay coincidencia en la tabla destino, se ejecuta la cláusula `when not matched by by target` y ocurre un insert en la tabla
- Cuando hay un registro en la tabla destino que no tienen coincidencia en la tabla origen, se ejecuta la cláusula `when not matched by source` y, en este caso, se elimina el registro en la tabla destino.

El resultado, tal como está escrita la consulta del ejemplo, va a dejar las dos tablas con idéntica información.

Comment: Buen día, su código funciono a la perfección!, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Deberías tener dos consultas, la primera insertaría los registros no existentes (mediante un `INSERT` y el operador `not in`) y la segunda actualizaría los datos (mediante un `UPDATE` igualando la clave primaria de ambas tablas).

**Insertamos los datos**

```
INSERT INTO regiones2 (regionID, campo1, campo2, ...)
SELECT regionID, campo1, campo2, ...
FROM Regiones
where regionID not in (select regionID from regiones2)
```

**Actualizamos todos los datos**

```
UPDATE region2
SET Campo1 = b.Campo1, Campo2 = b.Campo2
FROM region2 a
INNER JOIN region b on a.regionID = b.regionID
```

Es importante remarcar que el campo `regionID` es la clave de las dos tablas

Comment: Excelente explicación, funciona!